# How to hide some cells for edit view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an iPhone app with a detail view in a nav controller.  When I enter edit mode, some of the cells get a disclosure indicator added to them.  I also want some of the cells to disappear when in edit mode.  All the tableView: delegate messages check if it is in editing mode and display the correct cells accordingly, but entering editing mode does not trigger a reload.  If I call

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

in setEditing:animated:, I get the desired result, but I lose the transition animation - the '>' suddenly appears instead of fading in.  Is there a way to hide some cells for edit mode and still have the transition effects?

jorj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need logic to determine which cells should be on the screen and which cells need to disappear and then use the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method to remove the ones you want to animate out.